# Menu Animation On Page Scrolling - Css or Jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, web

I can't understand if menu animations that happen on page scrolling can be done via css alone or need jquery\other stuff.

A few examples to clarify:

1. http://www.optimo-it.com/products/uCast/
2. http://demo.teothemes.com/?theme=scrn
3. http://demo.brankic.net/?theme=BigBangWP

Also, if anyone happens to know some tutorial on the subject, that'd be greatly appreciated as i'd love to implement a similar animation on my personal website.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need some jQuery/JavaScript for sure. jQuery/Javascript will use your css to complete the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it reacts to scrolling, that is, changes depending on where you scroll within a page, then it should be done with javascript by capturing the scoll event. Using jQuery it would be somenthing like:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  ...
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > threshold) {
    // Do stuff
  }
});
```

However, you can keep the menu in a fixed position using css `position:fixed`. This approach will not give you nice animations, it will simply keep the menu fixed on the screen.

Comment: Thanks!




Now that i know where to look, it will be easier to try and see if i can get it done!


And yes, i know i could simply keep the menu fixed into his position, but i was looking for something a little more eye appealing :p


Also thanks to the other people who replied and to Rohan Kumar for fixing the layout of my post!